# Ubuntu Cloud UEC 12.04 amd64 image has an invalid locale

Tags: 64-bit, kvm-virtualization, locale, uec

Following the tutorial in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#DownloadUECImages I was able to execute the Ubuntu 12.04 Cloud Image (amd64) in my computer (http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img), so I can add whatever I want before uploading it to my Openstack Cloud. However, when I log in I receive a message saying that my environment specifies an invalid locale. In order to sort this out, I run locale-gen, obtaining the following:

```
ubuntu@ovfdemo:~$ sudo locale-gen 
sudo: unable to resolve host ovfdemo
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 243:  1435 Killed                  localedef $no_archive -i $input -c -f $charset $locale_alias $locale
failed
Generation complete.

ubuntu@ovfdemo:~$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX

ubuntu@ovfdemo:~$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This does not happen in the i386 version of the same image (http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-i386-disk1.img). What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. It was because the RAM memory I used to boot the image was not enough. I used the qemu -m flag and used a value such as 256 and it worked.